# Easiest way to get `+` indented `tree` output

Tags: sed, string, replace, output, tree

I need to replace indentation in `tree` output with + signs so that instead of this:

```bsh
$ tree --noreport dir
dir
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── dir2
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

it'd print this:

```bsh
$ tree --noreport dir
+ dir
++ dir1
+++ file1
+++ file2
++ dir2
+++ file1
+++ file2
```

It seems trivial enough, I pipe output to `sed` and replace stuff like so:

```bsh
tree --noreport | sed -e 's/├── \|└── /+ /g' -e 's/│   \|    /+/g' -e 's/^/+/' -e '1s/+/+ /'
```

But it has caveats (e.g. if there are 4 spaces in directory or file name for whatever reason) so I can't stop to wonder if there's a better way.

Edit: In this particular case I need to do it with `tree` as I get a bunch of tree flags as output from external tool and in order to use `find` I'd have to translate these which might be possible but I don't think it's worth the time since I already have a sub-optimal working solution. I asked this question because I was sure I'm overcomplicating the problem and missing something obvious.

Comment: Parsing `tree`-output seems error-prone.  What is it you need to do in the first place?  Why do you need to represent directory-depth with `+`?

Comment: I needed to visualise (in PlantUML using Salt - it takes `+` indented trees) the order in which an external tool traversed directories and read files. That external tool uses `tree` internally with different flags depending on user input and logs these flags in result file. I had 300+ use cases to visualise. My solution isn't optimal. I wanted to know if there's a better way than bunch of `sed` substitutions.

Comment: Hm. My terminal at work shows graphical output like in your question, my terminal at home does not.  It may be safer to use `tree -iJ` to get back a json-document and work from there.  But that will require additional tools to do the json-parsing.  Same for the xml-output-variant `tree -iX`.  Hm... *think*

Comment: This is actually a good point. I didn't think about parsing from alternative output format. It seems valid. I'll look into that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and `perl`:

```
find dir -printf "print '+'x(%d + 1),' ','%f','\n';\n" | perl
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `find` is not an option as I need `tree`-s flags to work. Other than that, this solution throws syntax errors on my install, e.g.:

`Bareword found where operator expected at - line 83, near "8c"
    (Missing operator before c?)
[...]
syntax error at - line 15, near "my-"
syntax error at - line 83, near "8c"
syntax error at - line 93, near "8e"`

Comment: Yes, a space in the filename would have triggered that. I just fixed. If it is just the `tree -s` flag you need to work, then add the filesize to the print. `find` has tons of possibilities. Could you put in the question the actual output you want to have?

Comment: I'd have to experiment where `find` falls compared to `tree` to add a sufficiently complicated example. The issue is I have an external tool that internally uses `tree` and it can spit the tree flags it used. I need to visualise which files and directories it worked on and in what order. In CLI I can just run `tree` with those flags but I need to put it in PlantUML and managed to do so with Salt widget. Salt takes tree output but with `+` indentation as in original question. I could use `find` but would need a whole layer of abstraction to translate those flags and it's not worth it, I think.

Comment: What I mean is, we are trying to reproduce the output you listed. But there is no size there, so we cannot really help. An actual output from tree and what you want to achieve (just some lines) would make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

One way to generate this kind of output but the ordering could be different is :

```
$ find ./dir | sed -E ':a;s|/[^/]+/|+/|;ta' | tr / \  | sed s/./+/
```

Result for the same directory structure:

```
+ dir
++ dir2
+++ file2
+++ file1
++ dir1
+++ file2
+++ file1
```